# git push via ssh to ubuntu VM not working but I am able to ssh to the same ubuntu

Tags: git

I have setup of ubuntu Guest VM on Virtualbox on MAC HOST.

I have setup the ubuntu as server with the [help](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

Created ssh key and put the public key on the Ubuntu and I am able to ssh

I have added remote repo like this

```
git remote add origin `ssh://git@192.168.1.8:/var/opt/repo-demo.git`
```

but I am not able do a git push to the Ubuntu VM.

However I am able to login via ssh as git user like ssh git@192.168.1.8

tried with `git push --verbose` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misinpreting single quotes and backquotes, both in the commands you issued and in your question. (Seems to be typical for Apple users).

The backquote (below the tilde `~` on a US qwerty) keyboard is different from `'`, and if you do

```
`ssh://git@192.168.1.8:/var/opt/repo-demo.git`
```

the backquotes will make this execute as if you had put `$( )` around that expression. Since bash cannot execute that expression, it will return "No such file or directory", and the `git remote add origin` will fail. Double
check your `.git/config` file, and update it by hand.

Be careful of using inappropriate quotes, especially on the Ubuntu commandline (but of course also when writing *doesn't* )